# How to use a SQL inside Teradata UDF?

Tags: sql, oracle, teradata, user-defined-functions

I want to convert a complex query into a reusable and parameterized function.
Thus I am trying to create an UDF in Teradata, but do not understand how to use SQL inside my UDF.

Below is the sample UDF from Oracle database. Can anyone please confirm if & how I can create similar in Teradata ?

---

```
   CREATE FUNCTION test_ak (a IN NUMBER) 
   RETURN NUMBER 
   IS b NUMBER(10);
   BEGIN       
          SELECT a+1      
          INTO b
          FROM dual ;     
     RETURN(b);
   END;
   /
```

Comment: This is simply increasing a by 1, would be `replace function test_ak(a number) returns number deterministic return a+1;` But you probably want something more complex. Teradata doesn't allow Select in SQL-UDFs, just calculations

Comment: Thank you Dieter for the confirmation..
You are right, I wanted more complex SQL, my example was not very good...